# Clear last line in browser console or specefic type of error using javascript?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Is there any way to clear the last line in the browser console or clear a specific type of error in general (e.g. network errors) using javascript?

I want to use `console.clear` but it only removes some lines.

Comment: JS doesn't have that fine of control over the console. You clear it all or nothing. And you can't prevent network errors from being displayed in the console, with the exception of the user themselves setting a filter. If this is for general use for other users then you probably don't have to worry about it as most users don't open the console. Otherwise if it is just for your own use you can just use the filter settings in the console pane

Comment: I don't see any usecase. You can just filter the output if you want to get a better overview.